# dropdown menu item in css positioning

Tags: html, css

I want to make a dropdown menu in CSS ... I already have a menu with "fixed" position(this first menu has to be fixed and nothing else)
but when I try to design my dropdown menu, items in it don't go to the position I want and always align to the first menu...
plz, tell how to do it correctly....

```css
#menu {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 50%;
            margin-left: 25%;
            background-color: #333;
            color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .menu-content {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 25px 20px;
            font-size: 17px;
        }
        #products {
            padding-top: 25px;
            font-size: 22px;
        }     
        .dropdown {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .dropdown .dropdown-btn {
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            background-color: inherit;
        }
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .dropdown-content a {
            float: none;
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: center ;
        }       
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button id="products" class="dropdown-btn menu-content"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> products  </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a> speaker </a>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </div
</body>
```

**this is the result I get:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRPKJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
#menu {
  overflow: hidden; <--remove!!
}
```

and add

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 65px; <- Add
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use overflow:hidden on your #menu your dropdownlist will never show up, because your list will be limited by the external div, since it's nested in.
Also, use margin-top to add some distance between each item.

Answer (score 0):

a way to fix it is to change the positioning from absolute to relative. also add a way to position it

```
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;<-- change to relative-->
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        z-index: 1;
```